# How to translate CURL request into AJAX call without getting %22 for quotes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, curl

I have a CURL request which is working fine:

```
curl --request GET \
 --url http://localhost:3001/api/v1/protected/getmydetails \
 --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2dvbnRvLmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6Im5vZGVqcy1qd3QtYXV0aCIsImV4cCI6MTUzMzc2OTE0MCwic2NvcGUiOiJmdWxsX2FjY2VzcyIsInN1YiI6ImxhbGFsYW5kfGdvbnRvIiwianRpIjoiQktBZW9KUVNBY3dBZ1A0dyIsImFsZyI6IkhTMjU2IiwiaWF0IjoxNTMzNzQ0MzQwfQ.xM6n2NNEoyY234vbNEnHJsp3My9BmnYtzd1JHmvIyUU' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data '{
  "id_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyIwIjoidCIsIjEiOiJvIiwiMiI6Im0iLCIzIjoibSIsIjQiOiJ5IiwiNSI6Il8iLCI2IjoiTCIsIjciOiJhIiwiOCI6InciLCJpYXQiOjE1MzM3NDQzNDAsImV4cCI6MTUzNTU0NDM0MH0.WZ47z_xytiyH3LlEYsfvApIfa4H92Tf2sGsGFZ4rRyE"
}'
```

However, I struggle with forming the corresponding AJAX call.

```
<script>
var id_tok = Cookies.get('id_token');
var access_tok = Cookies.get('access_token');

var dataLoad = JSON.stringify({
  id_token: id_tok
});

$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
  url:   'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/protected/getmydetails',
 headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_tok },
  data: dataLoad,
  contentType: 'application/json'
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log('data called success');
});
```

I inspect the network call in Chrome which has the Request URL:

```
http://localhost:3001/api/v1/protected/getmydetails?{%22id_token%22:%22eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyIwIjoidCIsIjEiOiJvIiwiMiI6Im0iLCIzIjoibSIsIjQiOiJ5IiwiNSI6Il8iLCI2IjoiTCIsIjciOiJhIiwiOCI6InciLCJpYXQiOjE1MzM3NDQ4ODgsImV4cCI6MTUzNTU0NDg4OH0.ixgm2LHb6iPAbrfQmtwINin_RBeBa5nu29yevbtEi74%22}
Request Method: GET
```

I pretty sure to narrow the error down to the transmission of `id_token` and that the "" being resolved into `%22`.

What I don't get is why do the quotes get translated into `%22` and not into quotes?

The node.js server returns `500 (Internal Server Error) which is caused by a QueryResultError: 0`

Comment: The quotes are a result of the URL encoding process.  RFC 3986 specifies certain "reserved" characters that can appear as-is in the URL.  Everything else must be encoded with %NN.  In the case of a double-quote, it's converted to %22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kevin628 said in comments, `%22` is the proper way to send `"` in a http request. I'm almost sure that your problem is within the header in the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), instead of `headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_tok }` you should try

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + access_tok);
  },
```

Then the code should be something like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
   url:   'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/protected/getmydetails',
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + access_tok);
  },
   data: dataLoad,
   contentType: 'application/json'
 }).done(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   console.log('data called success');
 });
```

Comment: This one gives as well the QueryResultError: 0 which is a 500 Internal Server error. I have another api call using the same authentication but without passing data which is working fine

Comment: What happen if you paste this in the browser http:// localhost:3001/api/v1/protected/getmydetails?{%22id_token%22:%22eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyIwIjoidCIsIjEiOiJvIiwiMiI6Im0iLCIzIjoibSIsIjQiOiJ5IiwiNSI6Il8iLCI2IjoiTCIsIjciOiJhIiwiOCI6InciLCJpYXQiOjE1MzM3NDQ4ODgsImV4cCI6MTUzNTU0NDg4OH0.ixgm2LHb6iPAbrfQmtwINin_RBeBa5nu29yevbtEi74%22}  keep in mind you could edit the request headers in the browser to try, so you could add the Authorization header there.

Comment: Thank you: This is coming up: UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found.
Could it be that my tokens are not stored correctly as cookies and I need to format them? 
The thing which I don't understand is how can it be an authorization problem when I can access a protected route just fine but without passing data?

Comment: Try console.log(id_tok) and console.log(access_tok)

Comment: Could it be that by doing the request the parameter get trimmed to 256 bits or something like that? The token is over 300 chars long

Comment: I think get request could support at least 2k as length, so you are far from there. In the raw request header, do you see Authorization: ? I mean in the browser's console tab network and request headers.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out a solution. I just modify the api call into /:id_tok and and pass it along the url without using the data object and your beforeSend. With that modification, it works like a charm.